# Laravel route model binding: return json response when model id not found

Tags: laravel

I'm developing a REST API in Laravel. I'm using route model binding to update an item. I want to return a JSON not found response when the id is not found in the database.

This is the entry in the route `api.php` file:

```
   Route::get('product/{product}', 'ProductController@show')->name('products.show');
```

The controller update function looks as follows:

```
   public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'user_id'       =>  'required',
            'name'          =>  'nullable',
            'description'   =>  'nullable',
            'price'         =>  'nullable'
        ]);

        // check if currently authenticated user is the owner of the listing

        if (auth::user()->id !== $product->user_id) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'You can only edit your own products.'], 403);
        }

        $product->update($request->only(['name', 'description', 'price']));

        return new ProductResource($product);
    }
```

With this code,  Laravel automatically returns a `404 Not found` view but I would like it to be a JSON response instead.

Any elegant solution to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to modify `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file with something like that:

```php
// add this before the class declaration
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
//....
// modify the render() function as follows
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException && $request->wantsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Not Found'], 404);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Let me know if it works I didn't have the time to try the code.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. No, this does not work. I added this code already previously. It captures only when the API route does not exist in the route file. But I would need to find something where the API exists in the route file but the ID (of the passed product) is not in the database.

Comment: Please read carefully my code I posted a condition on a ModelNotFoundException not on NotFoundHttpException, they are two different things.

Comment: Apologies, did indeed not notice it. Your code is working for this use case but only when I remove the `&& $request->wantsJson()` part.

Comment: Ok if you are designing a JSON API it could be the right thing to do. That depends on your request, if it's a JSON request or not. My advice is to use the accept application/json header on client side.

Comment: OK, I was using `Content-Type application/json`. Maybe that was the reason it failed. Will accept the answer as now it works when setting it to `Accept application/json`

Answer (score 3):

In the recent Laravel version (9) you can solve this by putting the below code inside the register function in app/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
  $this->renderable(function (NotFoundHttpException $exception) {
         return response()->json([
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'Your message here',
           ], 404);
     });
```

Ensure to import the namespace of NotFoundHttpException.
If your own error is ModelNotFoundException then do it this way

```
  $this->renderable(function (ModelNotFoundException $exception) {
         return response()->json([
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'Your message here',
           ], 404);
     });
```